# Completion Suggester TokenStream expanded Error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 1.7.2. My analyzer for filled_by_suggest field

```
 "company_analyzer": {
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "filter": [
      "shingle_filter"
    ]
  }
```

shingle filter

```
"shingle_filter": { 
    "type": "shingle", 
    "min_shingle_size": 2, 
    "max_shingle_size": 5
   }
```

Mapping for field

```
"filed_by_suggest" : {"type" : "completion", "analyzer" : "company_analyzer"}
```

When I do

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "filed_by_suggest": "timothy M  Hogan - AZ Ctr  for Law in the Public Interest"
}
```

I get following Error

```
{
   "error": "IllegalArgumentException[TokenStream expanded to 1793 finite strings. Only <= 256 finite strings are supported]",
   "status": 500
}
```

But when I try to index larger string like

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "filed_by_suggest": "alliance telecommunications corp., hector communications corporation, golden west telecommunications cooperative, inc., splitrock telecom coop., inc., ollig utilities co., sioux valley telephone co., hills telephone co. inc., sleepy eye te"
}
```

This operation is successful. I know a bit about **FST** which is internally used by completion suggester.

Could anyone please explain How tokens are expanded and How to address this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you find any fix?

Comment: @usef_ksa No, I could not solve the problem, I actually changed the analyzer to `keyword` as `completion suggester` works from the beginning of the string only, [this](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/8973242-tokenstream-error-only-256-finite-strings-are-supported) might be useful

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your analyzer.

The input string, will be split into tokens by analyzer, you can test and count tokens with `_analyze` API.